# Pattern regex substitution in Notepad++

Tags: regex, shell, unix, notepad++

How do I achieve this kind of regex substitution in Notepad++ & Linux / Unix Korn shell (Plain BSD Linux)?

```
z1.9z.01.01           Yabdadba do 
da.8p.25.7p           Foobar
tg.7j.75.2q           Whatever
90.6q.88.zx           Jane Doe
```

Note the           char. I am not sure what you want to call it.

Substitution #1 
o/p should be

```
Yabdadba do 
Foobar
Whatever
Jane Doe
```

Substitution #2 
o/p should be

```
   9z           Yabdadba do 
   8p           Foobar
   7j           Whatever
   6q           Jane Doe
```

Substitution #3 
 
o/p should be

```
z1.9z.01.01 
da.8p.25.7p
tg.7j.75.2q
90.6q.88.zx
```

I tried using `^.*` and `$` with the regex option, but it won't do anything.

Comment: What did you try? What did you obtain?

Comment: Thank you very much Everyone. I wish i could choose more than 1 ans and leave em as tie breakers. But it wont lemmw...bur Thank you nonetheless .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the assumption that the parts are fixed and of this form XX.XX.XX.XX

*For Substitution # 1*
Find `(?m)^[^.\s]{2}(?:\.[^.\s]{2}){3}[^\S\r\n]+(?=\S.*)`
Replace `nothing`

```
 (?m)                          # Multi-line mode
 ^                             # BOL
 [^.\s]{2}                     # Four parts separated by dot's
 (?: \. [^.\s]{2} ){3}
 [^\S\r\n]+                    # Whitespace following
 (?= \S .* )                   # Must be some text here
```

*For Substitution # 2*
Find `(?m)^[^.\s]{2}\.([^.\s]{2})(?:\.[^.\s]{2}){2}(?=[^\S\r\n]+\S.*)`
Replace `'   $1      '`

```
 (?m)                          # Multi-line mode
 ^                             # BOL
 [^.\s]{2}                     # Four parts separated by dot's

 \. 
 ( [^.\s]{2} )                 # (1)
 (?: \. [^.\s]{2} ){2}
 (?=                           # Whitespace following
      [^\S\r\n]+ 
      \S .*                         # Must be some text here
 )
```

*For Substitution # 3*
Find `(?m)^([^.\s]{2}(?:\.[^.\s]{2}){3})[^\S\r\n]+\S.*`
Replace `$1`

```
 (?m)                          # Multi-line mode
 ^                             # BOL
 (                             # (1 start), Four parts separated by dot's
      [^.\s]{2} 
      (?: \. [^.\s]{2} ){3}
 )                             # (1 end)
 [^\S\r\n]+                    # Whitespace following
 \S .*                         # Must be some text here
```

Comment: Thank you very much Everyone. I wish i could choose more than 1 ans and leave em as tie breakers. But it wont lemmw...bur Thank you nonetheless .

Answer (score 1):

`^([a-z0-9]+?[.]([a-z0-9]+?)[.][a-z0-9]+?[.][a-z0-9]+?[ ]+(.+)$`

Capture group 1 contains the dotted strings

Capture group 2 contains the second term of the dotted strings

Capture group 3 contains the names on the right side.

You can try at [regex tester online](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much Everyone. I wish i could choose more than 1 ans and leave em as tie breakers. But it wont lemmw...bur Thank you nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Unix shell:

1. `cut -f2 yourfile` or `awk '{print $2}' yourfile`
2. `awk -F"[\t.]" '{print $2, $5}' yourfile`
3. `cut -f1 yourfile` or `awk '{print $1}' yourfile`

`cut` selects fields from files, so your first and last question demanded to select the second and first field. `awk` is more versatile but can be used for the same task. 
Your second question asks for printing the second and fifths fields (fields separated by either tab or ".").

Comment: Thank you very much Everyone. I wish i could choose more than 1 ans and leave em as tie breakers. But it wont lemmw...bur Thank you nonetheless .

Answer (score 0):

For `notepad++` :

**Substitution # 1**

<kbd>find</kbd> =  `^.*?\s+(.*?)$`
<kbd>repalce</kbd> =  `\1`

---

**Substitution # 2**

<kbd>find</kbd> =  `^(\w{2})\.(\w{2})\.(\w{2})\.(\w{2})\s+(.*?)$`
<kbd>repalce</kbd> =  `\2 \5`

---

**Substitution # 3**

<kbd>find</kbd> =  `^([a-z0-9.]+).*?$`
<kbd>repalce</kbd> =  `\1`

Comment: Thank you very much Everyone. I wish i could choose more than 1 ans and leave em as tie breakers. But it wont lemmw...bur Thank you nonetheless